# How can I install the standard libraries for a Python that doesn't have them?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a system that has installed Python 2.7, but not the standard libraries like `minidom`, etc. I guess it is a broken install. How can I fix that and install separately the standard libraries for that Python?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: have you tried `import xml.dom.minidom` instead of `import minidom` ?

Comment: @Tichodroma It was not a standard distribution custom made

Comment: If your installation is a custom installation you'll have to ask the person who customized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should totally uninstall the python, and reinstall a full-package version.
Standard lib comes with install package, it's hard to separate it.

Answer (score 1):

(As it is standard library, it should have been shipped with python, thus no need to explicitly download)

Try importing like this:

> from xml.dom import minidom

or

> import xml.dom.minidom

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, try

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

and then double-tap [tab], showing most python libraries ready to download.
Otherwise you could try reinstalling python

Answer (score 1):

All this libraries are automatically installed with python may there should be a problem at installation time you can try this sudo apt-get update i am not sure for this.
If this does not solve your issue the better way is completely uninstall python and reinstall it.